# Dark matter/dark energy in Einstein's equation as manifestations of entropy production

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, entropy, dark-matter, dark-energy

It is well known that pressure adds a contribution to the gravity sources in Einstein's equation.  That contribution is unknown in Newton's theory.  What about entropy itself, or more precisely the time variation of its local density $\sigma$ ?  In natural units, $\frac{d\sigma}{dt}$ has the same dimensions (i.e units) as pressure $p$ and energy density $\rho$.

In the usual classical formulation of Einstein's equation, the second law of thermodynamics (i.e the time variation of entropy) isn't included as a source term.  In most cosmological applications of General Relativity, the entropy is considered constant, so $\frac{d\sigma}{dt} = 0$ (the expansion of space is considered as an adiabatic process).  For the usual cosmological *perfect fluid*:
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\nabla_{\mu} T^{\mu \nu} = 0 \qquad &\Rightarrow \qquad \frac{d\rho}{dt} + 3 H (\rho + p) = 0 \\[3ex]
&\Rightarrow \qquad dE = -\, p \, dV \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad dS = 0. \tag{2}
\end{align}

How the entropy of the universe could increase during expansion, if we suppose that it is filled with a perfect fluid only?

Is it possible that dark matter and/or dark energy could be a manifestation of the second law of thermodynamics not included into Einstein's equation?  How should the classical Einstein's equation be modified so the variation of entropy be included into the right part?
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
G_{\mu \nu} = -\, \kappa \, T_{\mu \nu} + \text{?},
\end{equation}
where the new part could include $\frac{d\sigma}{dt}$ as a new contribution to gravity, like pressure ($\sigma$ is the local entropy density).

So in brief, the idea is that the production of entropy in a system could be another source of gravity, like pressure, momentum and energy densities, and that this new source could manifest as "dark matter" or "dark energy" (or both?).  Is this idea have been considered before?

Comment: Entropy emerges as collective effect on macroscopic scale, while EFE is applied on local microscopic scale. Even if we introduce some entropy density function on local scale, how do we know that we can apply the same classical laws of thermodynamics? Gravitational field also carries entropy in the sense that not all gravitational energy can be extracted to perform useful work (see Penrose process). You could still include entropy in fluid $T_{ab}$ (see for instance https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0605010.pdf)

Comment: At a 2020 conference in Lima, Nikodem Poplawski, using Einstein-Cartan Theory, implied that relativity might be connected to QM thru consideration of the space occupied by each fermion as equivalent to a discrete space, so maybe the unit of time involved would be the time it takes an ECT fermion to rotate.  (I'm not sure how closely this connects to the question, but Poplawski did some earlier work on DE, found by his name on on Arxiv, & I recall that the OP's familiar with ECT's notation.)  There's a conference transcript at  https://indico.uni.edu.pe/event/85/timetable/?print=1&view=standard